# Sum all digits of a number and show the digits separately in Java

Tags: java, numbers, digits

I've been using this site quite a lot but I've never really wrote anything.
Today, I've stumbled upon a problem which solution I can't seem to find.

The problem is that, I have an `int variable` with an unknown number of digits. It is asked of me to sum all of those digits and then have it printed/shown_as_a_message with all those digit separated.

For example, the user enters the number "12345678" and in the end I need to have a message saying "The numbers 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 36". I know how to separate and sum all of those numbers, but I don't know how to save each number and then have it shown, because not only do I not know the right amount of digits, but I don't know their values either.

Usually that wouldn't be hard to do, but here comes the tricky part for me, since we haven't learned things like `arrays`, `strings`, indexes, etc., we're not allowed to use them. So, I'm supposed to do it with the simplest type of code possible.

So far, I've got the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number, result;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number:");
        number = sc.nextInt();
        result = 0;
        while (number > 0){
            result = result + (number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
        }
        System.out.println("This is where the message would go.");
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats the issue again with this code?It seems to do the job with your constraints

Comment: How are you going to print anything if you can't use Strings? One char at a time?

Comment: Try to save each number in a String, may be you should reverse it before looping with charAt and print the "1+2+3+ .." version

Comment: Can't use String nor charAt.
I am to just write the whole number and work with mostly numbers.

Comment: @DoombringerBG can you print the numbers in reverse order?

Comment: @LukeMelaia I don't think I'm allowed.

Comment: `"12345678".replaceAll("\\B", " + ")` ➜ `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8`

Comment: @Andreas I love you. <3
Edit: I'm new and I don't know how to mark this as the solution, so I'll just edit my original post and give you credit there. :3

Comment: @Squiddie Dang it. :(

Comment: I did it in a recursive version, what do you think about?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use "private static int reverse(int number)". Right now they've only told use to use "public static void main(String[] args)". :(

Comment: @Squiddie how can you move a recursive method in the main? I think it is not possible..

Comment: I already appointed a solution, but for some reason I feel bad, so I'll mention him as well.

Comment: Pro-tips for posting here: put solutions in an answer below; we don't use [solved] title hacks here, as we have an acceptance system; use double-return to create a paragraph; line break tags are almost never needed in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number, result;
    System.out.println("Enter number:");
    number = input.nextInt();
    result = 0;
    System.out.print("The numbers: ");

    //Reverses the number
    int reversedNum = 0;
    while (number != 0) {
        reversedNum = reversedNum * 10 + number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }

    //Iterates over the number and prints it out
    while (reversedNum > 0) {
        System.out.print((reversedNum % 10));

        result = result + (reversedNum % 10);
        reversedNum = reversedNum / 10;

        if (reversedNum > 0) {
            System.out.print(" + ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" = " + result);
}
```

This works to print out all the numbers in the correct order without using arrays and strings.

Example:

```
Enter number:
12345
The numbers: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this where you aren't using any sort of container. Simply concatenate to the string each of time you find a new number.

```
    int number, result;
    String finalOutput = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number:");
    number = sc.nextInt();
    result = 0;

    while (number > 0){
        result = result + (number % 10);

        finalOutput += (number % 10);

        number = number / 10;
        if(number > 0)
        {
            finalOutput += " + ";
        }else{
            finalOutput += " = ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The numbers " + finalOutput + result);
```

Comment: Note that this will print the digits in reverse: `8 + 7 + ...`. The desired output is `1 + 2 + ...`.

Comment: Even if it's in reverse, it's something. Seems very interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print out these numbers as you are looping. Ex:

```
while (number > 0){
     System.out.print( (number % 10) + " + " );
     result = result + (number % 10);
     number = number / 10;
}
```

You still have the task of getting your output formatted correctly.

Comment: This is very interesting. I might be able to come up with something using something similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task a year ago. Basically what I did is to turn the inputted integer into a String using `String.valueOf(int)` (`Integer.toString(int)` works too) then I turn every char in that String back to integers and adds them to the sum.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int sum= 0;

System.out.println("Number?");
int num = sc.nextInt();
sc.close();

String countNum = String.valueOf(num);

for(int i = 0; i < countNum.length(); i++) {
   int j = Character.digit(countNum.charAt(i), 10);
   sum += j;
}
System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: I can't use String, countNum.length, Character.digit, nor charAt.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively:

```
int number,result;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number:");
number = sc.nextInt();
//sum to the result and print last digit and the result
int last = number%10;
result = reverse(number/10);
System.out.print(last + " = "+ (result + last));
```

Recursive method, print the string and compute the sum (except last digit):

```
private static int reverse(int number) {
    if(number>0){
        int p = number % 10 + reverse(number/10);
        System.out.print(number % 10 + " + ");
        return p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use s.append, s.reverse, s.lenght, and s.charAt.

Comment: @DoombringerBG I update the answer. I did it recursively.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok using regular expressions, and simply want to insert a plus sign surrounded by spaces between all the digits, you can use the [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method:

```
"12345678".replaceAll("\\B", " + ") // returns "1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8"
```

`\\B` is the regular expression for matching the empty positions between characters that are *not* word breaks (`\\b` would be positions that *are* word breaks). Since the input is a single "word" consisting of all digits, the beginning and end of the value are word breaks, and the positions between digits are not word breaks.

`replaceAll()` then replaces all those empty spaces between digits with `" + "`, and you get exactly what you wanted in a simple expression.

Comment: This would've been the solution, but I was told by Squiddie that "123456789" creates a String. :(

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Solved by Luke Melaia!

Another thing that might be helpful to people Google-ing this:

Shortest solution with String -> "12345678".replaceAll("\B", " + ") ➜ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 – **Andreas**

Recursive Solution by **user6904265**.

Thank you all for the great help. Much appreciated. <3

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Java8, you can do it by this way:

```
public int sumNumber(int number) {
        return String.valueOf(number).chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum();
    }
```

This might help to someone.